# Python numpy split with indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a numpy equivalent of my suboptimal Python code. The calculation I want to do can be summarized by:

> The average of the peak of each section for each row.

Here the code with a sample array and list of indices. Sections can be of different sizes.

```py
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
              [5, 6, 7, 8]])
indices = [2]
result = np.empty((1, x.shape[0]))
for row in x:
    splited = np.array_split(row, indexes)
    peak = [np.amax(a) for a in splited]
    result[0, i] = np.average(peak)
```

Which gives: `result = array([[3., 7.]])`

What is the optimized numpy way to suppress both loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just take off the `for` loop and use `axis` instead:

```
result2 = np.mean([np.max(arr, 1) for arr in np.array_split(x_large, indices, 1)], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([3., 7.])
```

Benchmark:

```
x_large = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                    [5, 6, 7, 8]] * 1000)
%%timeit
result = []
for row in x_large:
    splited = np.array_split(row, indices)
    peak = [np.amax(a) for a in splited]
    result.append(np.average(peak))

# 29.9 ms ± 177 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np.mean([np.max(arr, 1) for arr in np.array_split(x_large, indices, 1)], axis=0)

# 37.4 µs ± 499 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Validation:

```
np.array_equal(result, result2)
# True
```

Comment: There is a problem when section are not of the same size. `x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 8]])` should give the same result but fail with "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)"

Comment: @Jordan I've updated with list comprehension version. Can you give it a try ;)?